# Открытие окна при нажатии кнопки || PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

У меня не получается реализовать открытие ещё одного экрана по нажатию кнопки. При нажатии кнопки вылетает Process finished with exit code 1073741845. Если я пытаюсь заменить exec на 28 строке на show, то окно лишь вылетает на мгновение. Заранее благодарен.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from project_pyqt_des import Ui_MainWindow
from task_4 import Ui_MainWindow4


class FirstTask(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow4):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Задание №4')


class Application(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle(
            'Тренажёр для подготовки к ЕГЭ по русскому языку')

        self.task_4.clicked.connect(self.first_task)

    def first_task(self):
        window_4 = FirstTask()
        window_4.exec()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Application()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Вот дизайн основного окна

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(816, 460)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(816, 460))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(816, 460))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 801, 441))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.task_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_4.setFont(font)
        self.task_4.setObjectName("task_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.task_4)
        self.task_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_7.setFont(font)
        self.task_7.setObjectName("task_7")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.task_7)
        self.task_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_9.setFont(font)
        self.task_9.setObjectName("task_9")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.task_9)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.task_10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_10.setFont(font)
        self.task_10.setObjectName("task_10")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.task_10)
        self.task_11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_11.setFont(font)
        self.task_11.setObjectName("task_11")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.task_11)
        self.task_12 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_12.setFont(font)
        self.task_12.setObjectName("task_12")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.task_12)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.task_13 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_13.setFont(font)
        self.task_13.setObjectName("task_13")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.task_13)
        self.task_14 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_14.setFont(font)
        self.task_14.setObjectName("task_14")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.task_14)
        self.task_15 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_15.setFont(font)
        self.task_15.setObjectName("task_15")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.task_15)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.title_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.title_label.setFont(font)
        self.title_label.setObjectName("title_label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.title_label, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.task_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №4"))
        self.task_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №7"))
        self.task_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №9"))
        self.task_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №10"))
        self.task_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №11"))
        self.task_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №12"))
        self.task_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №13"))
        self.task_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №14"))
        self.task_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №15"))
        self.title_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Тренажёр для подготовки к ЕГЭ по русскому языку"))
```

Вот дизайн окна, вызываемого кнопкой "Задание №4"

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow4(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.task_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.task_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 10, 801, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(22)
        self.task_label.setFont(font)
        self.task_label.setObjectName("task_label")
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 130, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_14.setFont(font)
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.label_24 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_24.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 170, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_24.setFont(font)
        self.label_24.setObjectName("label_24")
        self.label_34 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_34.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 210, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_34.setFont(font)
        self.label_34.setObjectName("label_34")
        self.label_44 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_44.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 250, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_44.setFont(font)
        self.label_44.setObjectName("label_44")
        self.label_54 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_54.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 290, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_54.setFont(font)
        self.label_54.setObjectName("label_54")
        self.out_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.out_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 340, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.out_label.setFont(font)
        self.out_label.setObjectName("out_label")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 330, 651, 41))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(
            _translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.task_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow",
                                           "В одном из приведённых ниже слов допущена ошибка  в \n"
                                           "постановке ударения: НЕВЕРНО выделена буква, \n"
                                           "обозначающая ударный гласный звук. Выпишите это слово."))
        self.label_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1 слово"))
        self.label_24.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2 слово"))
        self.label_34.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3 слово"))
        self.label_44.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4 слово"))
        self.label_54.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5 слово"))
        self.out_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ:"))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow",
                                            "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
                                            "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
                                            "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
                                            "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
                                            "<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте это.

```
def first_task(self):
    self.window_4 = FirstTask()
    self.window_4.show()
```

Comment: Да, действительно помогло. Спасибо